# Snackbar or Toast AndroidTv

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Is Snackbar supported by leanback support library for AndroidTv? I am currently using `com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.1` and I would like to offer to user an option to continue video playback from where he left the app with a Snackbar with button.

Or is some similar UI dialog like pop up which would not overlay totally the screen?

The only solution which I know of would be to implement an overlaying fragment, but the question is: Are there some other options?

Answer (score 2):

Android TV does display toasts and snackbars, although there isn't an easy way to focus on that view.

An [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) may be a better way to notify the user and provide them with actions.

Alternatively, you could just make that an item in your app that the user can select or ignore.